# Converting a dict into a list

Tags: python

I have

```
{key1:value1, key2:value2, etc}
```

I want it to become:

```
[key1,value1,key2,value2] , if certain keys match certain criteria.
```

How can i do it as pythonically as possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[y for x in dict.items() for y in x]
```

For example:

```
dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}

print([y for x in dict.items() for y in x])
```

This will print:

```
['two', 2, 'one', 1]
```

Comment: How exactly does this translate?  I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: wow, didn't know that you can write comprehensions in that weird order +1

Comment: @vergenzt: To be honest, I had no idea that you could flatten lists like that either, but you can :D And as for understanding it, you have to read it in reverse order because that's just how `for in` associates.

Comment: @unkulunkulu it is actually a nested list comprehension

Comment: What if I need to filter out certain keys when creating the list ?

Comment: @user1008636 Just like usual comprehensions: `[y for x in dict.items() for y in x if x[0] not in filtered_out]`

Comment: @user1008636: Filter them out beforehand. (Edit: Yeah, what erickrf said `:)`)

Comment: @erickrf, not really, if you look at it as a nested comprehension, he uses `x` in the outer comprehension while it's being introduced in the inner.

Comment: I think this is often called the [Martelli Method ;-)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/298607)

Answer (score 6):

given a `dict`, this will combine all items to a tuple

```
sum(dict.items(),())
```

if you want a list rather than a tuple

```
list(sum(dict.items(),()))
```

for example

```
dict = {"We": "Love", "Your" : "Dict"}
x = list(sum(dict.items(),()))
```

`x` is then

```
['We', 'Love', 'Your', 'Dict']
```

Comment: I would vote for this, but I've run out of votes, hence this comment. Great solution!

Answer (score 2):

This code should solve your problem:

```
myList = []
for tup in myDict.iteritems():
    myList.extend(tup)

>>> myList
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient (not necessarily most readable or Python is)

```
from itertools import chain

d = { 3: 2, 7: 9, 4: 5 } # etc...
mylist = list(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems()))
```

Apart from materialising the lists, everything is kept as iterators.

Comment: @Lev - thanks for edit - typed it straight into SO - my fault

Answer (score 1):

Another entry/answer:

```
import itertools

dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}

bl = [[k, v] for k, v in dict.items()]
list(itertools.chain(*bl))
```

yields

```
['two', 2, 'one', 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = {"lol": 1 }
>>> l = []
>>> for k in a.keys():
...     l.append( k )
...     l.append( a[k] )
... 
>>> l
['lol', 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If speed matters, use extend to add the key, value pairs to an empty list:

```
l=[]
for t in sorted(d.items()):
    return l.extend(t)


>>> d={'key1':'val1','key2':'val2'}
>>> l=[]
>>> for t in sorted(d.items()):
...    l.extend(t)
... 
>>> l
['key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2']
```

Not only faster, this form is easier to add logic to each key, value pair.

Speed comparison:

```
d={'key1':'val1','key2':'val2'}

def f1():
    l=[]
    for t in d.items():
        return l.extend(t)

def f2():
    return [y for x in d.items() for y in x]

cmpthese.cmpthese([f1,f2])
```

Prints:

```
    rate/sec    f2     f1
f2   908,348    -- -33.1%
f1 1,358,105 49.5%     --
```